# Xamarin forms Get Request Not working for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have created an application in Xamarin forms with Visual studio 2017 Professional and Visual studio 2019 cumulative addition.

But i am able to hit post request in both protocol http and https, but i am not able to hit Get request in both protocol.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
           {
                
                var response1 = await client.GetStringAsync("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
                
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Xamrin.form version both 3.5 stable version and 4.6 stable version.

Not able to hit get request.

Comment: are you getting a timeout or other exception?  What HTTP response code do you get?  Have you tested the request using the browser on the device?

Comment: Yes i have tested it with browser, postman, fiddler every thing working fine with API. I am not getting any exception just my debugger go to the next statement.

Comment: its normal for the debugger to proceed to the next statement when it's an async operation.  Is your server logging a request from the client when this happens?  You may need to use a tool like Wireshark to actually inspect the request from the client

Comment: how can i used wireshark to capture request from mobile. My question is simple get request not working in xamrin, this code works fine in windows console application. Why it not working in xamrin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to change my code as below, after it everything is working fine.

```
 client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HelloWorld.MyApp");
        HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, targetUri);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
```